# Button only refreshes side

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have got an little page with an button on it:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="myButton" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

This button executes a Method, wich is adding antoher button to the page

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * Add a add button
         */
        Button btnAdd = new Button();
        btnAdd.ID = "btnAdd";
        btnAdd.Attributes.Add("class", "myLoginButton");
        btnAdd.Attributes.Add("style", "position:relative; left:10px");
        btnAdd.Text = "Add User";
        btnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
        placeHolderUsers.Controls.Add(btnAdd);  
    }
```

I want that second button to execute this method:

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        debugLabel.Text = "hello im clicked";
    }
```

Everything works perfectly wtih the second button. Its text is set, its postion is correct,... The only thing that isn't working is the click. If I click that Button my page is like refreshed. Only the first Button is shown again.

I have no idea why...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are adding the dynamic button in another button click handler i.e. `btnSave_Click` and on every page load you dynamic control is getting lost.

Please note you have to add dynamic controls after postback because after every you control will be lost. You need to add this inside `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` event:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btnAdd = new Button();
   btnAdd.ID = "btnAdd";
   btnAdd.Attributes.Add("class", "myLoginButton");
   btnAdd.Attributes.Add("style", "position:relative; left:10px");
   btnAdd.Text = "Add User";
   btnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
   placeHolderUsers.Controls.Add(btnAdd); 
}
```

You can check the documentation for adding a dynamic control [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me too keep my buttons displayed. Do you have any idea how to achive that button handler is executed?

Comment: @FelixGerber - Hey rest of your code should work and `btnAdd_Click` handler method shoud work. Just remember you will have to add the dynamic control and its handler after every postback.